# How to use a dictionary when an object is required as a keyword argument but dictionary values need to be passed?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, ui-automation

I have some class `Person` with `first_name`, `last_name`, `age` attributes (this is just a simplified example, the actual class has  >30 attributes).

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name=None, last_name=None, age=None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        ...
```

I create an instance of this class and assign values to its properties. Later I use this object to fill in the data on the site I test.

```
person = Person(first_name="Alex",last_name="Kennedy", age=33 ...)
```

Later I modify some fields on the site with the help of dictionary. I use it because only two fields are needed to be changed (Actual object has >30).

```
fields = {
    "first_name": "Greg",
    "last_name": "Austin"
}
```

In a different module I use `person` object to compare its first_name with is what is actually in UI (`person_name[1]` is the first value from the list which I get with Selenium).

```
def open_view(self, person):
    assert first_name[1].lower() == person.name.lower()
```

### The problem

The goal is to verify the final result, and for this I need to use `open_view` function. It is imported with module.

If I assign like this `person=fields`, I get the error, because `person.first_name` from my object is string and it cannot be assigned to a dictionary value.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'first_name'

def check_result(self, person, fields):
    open_view(person=fields)
```

Person object needs to be passed, not dictionary. I cannot pass is like this `person=fields["first_name"]` because it will the same error.

If passing like `open_view(fields["first_name"])` as expected the error occurs: `TypeError: only named arguments are allowed but ('Greg',) positional arguments were passed`

### The question

How can I use a dictionary, so its values could be used in `open_view()` function?

Both structures values are strings.

I searched for similar questions and found that I can use`namedtuple` for comparing my dictionary with object. But I do not clearly understand how to use it in this context.
What are approaches that can be used? I will very very grateful for any suggests.

Comment: Why don't you create a instance of `Person` using `fields` and pass it to the function that expects a person?

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this as one of the ways, but my instance has more then 30 properties. I am not sure if it will work. Maybe I really chose the harder way.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.